# How do I sort MySQL search results be relevance?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I'm using PDO to search a MySQL table for search results. My query looks like this

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username LIKE :username OR name LIKE :name ORDER BY uniqueid DESC LIMIT 6";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(':username', '%'.$query.'%');
$stmt->bindValue(':name', $query.'%');
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is that in my results array, the results that match like this:

```
$query.'%'
```

Should appear before results that match like this:

```
'%'.$query.'%'
```

Is there a way to sort results by such relevance without two queries, preferably in pure SQL?

Comment: use sphinx for search this search engine, and you can easy settings sort by relevance, because relevance search this is sorting by count click to link in result.

Comment: try this. change the order in the query : **$SQL = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username LIKE :username OR name LIKE :name ORDER BY  name LIKE :name DESC, uniqueid DESC LIMIT 6";**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, Eugene's answer seems the most appropriate in this case. Provided below is an alternate solution to the problem in general which allows further customizations in terms of sorting the result :

If you have data like this :

```
Id  Name
1   Aabbee
2   Aabriella
3   Aada
4   bahlelah
5   cailelah
6   daielah
7   gaisha
8   Aisha
9   Aishath
10  dalelh
11  Eleasha
```

Then, you can use the following query:

```
select '1' as Relevance,ID, Name from MyTable where Name like 'el%' /*The results with the priority (or relevance) should be first */
union
select '2' as Relevance,ID, Name from MyTable where Name like '%el%' and Name not like 'el%' /* The lower priority results go here*/
order by Relevance
```

This will result in:

```
Relevance   ID    Name
    1       11    Eleasha
    2       2     Aabriella
    2       4     bahlelah
    2       5     cailelah
    2       6     daielah
    2       10    dalelh
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but doesn't this count as two queries? Or is the impact in speed and performance minimal?

Comment: @15KanurajBeri No, this counts as a single query. Speed and performance is not a straightforward thing - it would depend on your particular case, the raw data size. Generally, it wouldn't matter for a small dataset.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer was perfect. It also leaves scope for later if I want to show the people you follow first. Accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You could order the results by the index of `$query` in `username` and `name`:

```
SELECT * FROM users
    WHERE username LIKE :username OR name LIKE :name
ORDER BY uniqueid DESC, INSTR(:query, username), INSTR(:query, name) LIMIT 6
```

Note, however, that ordering by results of a function requires full table scan in MySQL.

Comment: Thanks a lot! However, this particular query doesn't seem to be working. Maybe you could help me out? Thanks for taking the time to help out a PHP rookie.

Answer (score 0):

You can easy use this query:

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username LIKE :username OR name LIKE :name ORDER BY name LIKE :name DESC, uniqueid DESC LIMIT 6"; –
```